# AES key and iv from RSA private key

Tags: cryptography, aes, rsa, private-key, initialization-vector

Is there a relationship between the content of a private RSA key (private exponent, modulus and primes) and a AES-128-cbs key and iv?

I know that you can encrypt your private key using AES in which case
the AES-iv is supplied in the pem file and the AES-key is 
calculated using MD5 over secret-password and the first 8 bytes 
of the AES-iv.

However I have AES encrypted data and a private RSA key that I can read.
Is there a standard on how to derive the AES-key and AES-iv from the 
RSA key content,  maybe from the prime numbers inside. Is 
there some standard that is normally used?

Comment: Usually a lot of cryptographic standards and formats are covered by [PKCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS). I don't know the one you are talking about and, as stated, It seems pretty nonsense.

Comment: I actually dont know how the encryption is done, the only thing I have is that the data is AES encrypted, and I have RSA keys... I can see the key and iv (by setting a breakpoint at AES_decrypt()) and I see that the keys are read and processed, however I wonder weather there is a relationship between the keys and the AES decrypt...

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to derive an AES key from the RSA private key, because the party that would want to decrypt the AES ciphertext would probably also have to derive the AES key ... so do they really have access to the *private* key? Perhaps you mean [key encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) ([backup](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19121/13022))? You should probably describe more clearly what you want to achieve and what you have (system model). Also, since this has really not much to do with programming, consider asking an improved version on [crypto.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.

Comment: You're right, I didnt know there was a cryptographic forum as well, I'll post there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it makes no sense to have your symmetric key depending on your asymmetric.

Usually you also don't just encrypt one particular AES key with one RSA keypair. Instead what you usually want to do is to use for example someone's public key to encrypt a randomly generated AES key and send the RSA encrypted key along with the AES encrypted data to the recipient.
This way you can use a different symmetric key for every data package.

This is just one use case, but it illustrates why there is no reason for such a dependency.

Comment: I think this is what is done. The 128bit AES key is encrypted with RSA and supplied alongside the AES encrypted data. I wonder one more thing (I'm a encryption novice..): I can find the 128 bit (4 32bit words) key, but how is it with the IV? Is there a standard IV reset value to use?

Comment: I tried with IV 0 and I can see the decrypted data now!